# Stack Exchange sites look TERRIBLE in Internet explorer

Tags: bug, status-declined, fun, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

...Three.

[image]

It even causes a General Protection Fault!

Please fix this.

Comment: Where did you even...?

Comment: Doesn't this happen with *ANY* site if you use IE?

Comment: "Choose close. IEXPLORE will close.". You've lost me, Windows

Comment: windows 3.1 are you serious?

Comment: +1, simply for the effort it must have taken just to get a screenshot.

Comment: I know this is a joke, but [IE3 is not on the "supported browsers" list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Comment: @BilltheLizard [You can get an installer bundling every version from 1.0 through 8.0 from here.](http://utilu.com/IECollection/)

Comment: [You sir, win the Internet](http://cheezburger.com/View/4244481)

Comment: @Jeremy I trust your linked site with all my heart.

Comment: What actually looks terrible is the background on that toolbar.  "Guys, this is great, but I think the background needs some swirls."

Comment: +1.  Every site should support windows 3.1.

Comment: This was reported on Stack Overflow proper eight months ago: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=5515933&service=stackoverflow or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515933 (10k)

Comment: Chat is just as bad: "'Windows Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.'
I have been advised to restart my computer." ([source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/96273#96273)) That was for IE 4.01 and IE 5.01.

Comment: bahaha I had to ressurect a Windows For Workgroups VM the other day and I thoguht "Hmm, I wonder how SO renders", and it didn't even get as far as the screenshot above, it just blue-screened windows.

Comment: Some time ago I posted a screenshot here of Stack Overflow on Netscape Navigator 4.7...

Comment: how did you get IE3?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So does [microsoft.com](http://microsoft.com):

[image]

Comment: ***WHERE DID YOU GET IE1***

Comment: *WHERE!?!?!?!!?!?*

Answer (score 10):

<sup><sub>HA!!!!!!!!!!!</sub></sup>

### LESSON LEARNED:

## DONT USE WINDOWS 3.1 FOR USE WITH THE STACK EXCHANGE

#### BUT:  [Supported Browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

### Lemme try [Google](http://www.google.com):

[image]